# How to keep IM thread running on android?

Tags: android

I am building an android IM chat app which needs to keep a long connection to the server. However, on some android phones (not all android phones), when a user locks their phone the app and its thread (running in Service) are paused and the chat app can no longer receive messages.

I want to know how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You should use a `Service`.  There is never a guarantee that it will always stay running, but unlike activities, services are designed to run in the background.  They're more likely to stay running if you request foreground status.

You can find more information about services [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).

Comment: I am using service now.It seems on some android phones ,even the service is paused when user lock the phone.

Comment: How are you actually calling that Service and how have you implemented it?

Comment: Using service would be a nice idea. Services don't pause even the user locks the screen. I have tested it by playing a mp3 file.

Comment: Using service only seems  not suitable in this environment. I looked up in the net,somebody says using NDK to create a daemon process to monitor the service's lifecycle.I am trying this.

Comment: I don't think you need to use NDK here.The SDK service class will suffice your purpose.using NDK is not that easy.